# Characterization of fields via equations

Tags: abstract-algebra

> A field $F$ is a commutative ring with identity and with at least two elements such that for all $a$ not equal to $0$ and $b$ in $F$, the equation $ax= b$ has a unique solution in $F$.

Here is what I did, but it's wrong.

I will denote the identity element of $G$ by $e$.

Fix any $a$ and $b$ in $G$.

From the group axioms we know there is something called $a^{-1}$ in $G$ with the property that $a^{-1} * a = a * a^{-} = e$. Let $x = a^{-1} * b$;

this is an element of $G$ because of the group axioms (it comes from that $a^{-1}$ and $b$ are in $G$, and the fact that $*$ is a binary operation on $G$). than we get

$a * x = a * (a^{-1} * b)$ [from the definition of $x$]

$= (a * a^{-1}) * b$ [by the associative law]

$= e * b$ [by one of the properties of $a^{-1}$]

$= b$ [by the defining property of the identity element $e$].

This shows that there is indeed an element $x$ of $G$, namely $x = a^{-1} * b$, with the property that $a * x = b$. Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary elements of $G$.

Comment: A field has two operations, not just one, and you need to show cancellation holds on the multiplicative one with the exception of cancelling multiplication by zero. When you have an abelian group $G$, you have only one operation, and you have no zero element (in the sense of multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say exactly what $G$ is, but it seems like you're trying to construct an inverse in the *additive* group underlying your field - you don't know that $F^\times$ forms a group yet, since this is what you're trying to prove (where $F^\times$ is the set of nonzero field elements). Hence, it appears that you're assuming your conclusion.

Recall that a field is a commutative ring with $1$ (which we have) such that every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse. So all we need to do is to select a nonzero field element and give an inverse. Select $a \neq 0 \in F$. Because $1 \neq 0$, our assumption shows that

$$ax = 1$$

has a unique solution $x_0$; that is, $x_0$ is a right inverse for $a$. But we're in a commutative ring, so

$$x_0a = ax_0 = 1$$

so $x_0$ is also a left inverse for $a$. It follows that $a$ has a multiplicative inverse, completing the proof.

Comment: Just pointing out that the left inverse and the right inverse are the same for invertible elements even in noncommutative rings. Let $a^{-1}_l,a^{-1}_r$ be left,right inverses of $a$, and note that $a^{-1}_l=a^{-1}_laa^{-1}_r=a^{-1}_r$.

Comment: just wanted to sure that iam clear on it. So what i did was not right? all i have to do to prove is what you have?

Comment: @kate Yes, what you have is not correct (you make statements about the *additive* group - that is, the group under the operation $+$). The goal of the problem is to show that nonzero elements actually do form a group under the operation $*$, so you can't assume that it's a group already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you called $\,G\,$ what at first you called $\,R\,$....anyway: $\,G\,$ indeed is a group **with respect to addition** , so multiplicatively we have nothing but the bare fact that $\,G\,$ is a unitary semigroup...

What's left to be proved is that multiplicatively $\,G^*:=G\setminus\{0\}\,$ is a group, which ammounts to prove that every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse, and that's exactly what the given data tells you: let $\,0\ne a\in G\;$ , then there exists a unique

$$x\in G\;\;s.t.\;\;ax=1\implies x\;\;\text{is the wanted multiplicative inverse of}\;\;a$$